# WSO2 CEP export event streams, event receivers etc

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

I am new in WSO2 Cep and I would like to ask if anybody knows that how can I export the event streams, event receivers, etc. which I have create in order to have a backup, from the WSO2 CEP Management console?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CEP deployable artifacts that are created from Management Console are stored in the file system. You can find them in `<CEP_HOME>/repository/deployment/server` folder.

- Event Streams can be found in directory **eventstreams**
- Event Receivers can be found in directory **eventreceivers**
- Event Publishers can be found in directory **eventpublishers**
- Execution Plans can be found in directory **executionplans**

Then, just create a backup of above directories.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an artifacts from management console they are persisted in file system under CEP_HOME/repository/deployment/server. Under this directory you can find event streams, receivers, executions plans, etc. So you can take a backup of this folder to make a backup of your current artifacts.

Regards